# PictureBox.OnMouseDown not called when key is being pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have inherited `PictureBox` to add some extra features to it. I'm handling mouse down as shown below:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Now, If I press a key (e.g. 'T') and simultaneously click with the mouse, `OnMouseDown` is **not** called! If I don't press a key, it is indeed called. **What's going on?**

Sure I have inherited `PictureBox` but this behavior makes no sense.

### UPDATE

I discovered that this happens throughout the whole system. I forgot to mention that I'm using a touchpad (multitouch). In the Control Panel I can see "Synaptics ClickPad V8.1". I believe there is some setting in the system that disables the mouse/touchpad while typing. Still looking for it though.

Comment: Do you have a handler somewhere that handles key press/key down? Handlers are executed in the single thread, so while one is running others can't start.

Comment: Works for me.  You have something else getting in the way or intercepting the event outright.

Comment: Does it work for you with direct PictureBox?  If no, try PictureBox in a test project, if yes, slowly add inherited stuff back until you find what breaks it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zeel's answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/644428/how-to-enable-synaptics-touchpad-while-typing-without-disabling-palmcheck) did the trick. Basically, you need to disable the tap delay in Windows 8. Then it works!

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to provoke something like that, such as locking the thread, executing some operation that cancels mouse event or elevated/close CPU cycles.

I suspect that you've hooked some **key** event somewhere, so add `Application.DoEvents();` at the end of that key  event and it should execute concurrent events.

As a warning, **DoEvents** is mostly used in specific cases, since usually causes lag and it is not really the best way to go, you should find a way to execute events/actions on a separated thread or, maybe, use an auxiliary flag to identify a cooperative  task.